# Create default pages in wordpress multisite

Tags: multisite

I'm struggling with WordPress Multisite page creation when newly site created. I found some hooks to achieve this but the hook is not responding. Some of the resources I found on stack and other sites are https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40014419/wordpress-multisite-default-page-for-newly-created-site and http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-add-remove-default-pages-in-wordpress-multisite/

The hook mentioned in these resources not working in my multisite setup.

```
add_action('wpmu_new_blog', 'wpb_create_my_pages', 10, 2);

function wpb_create_my_pages($blog_id, $user_id){
  switch_to_blog($blog_id);

// create new page
  $page_id = wp_insert_post(array(
    'post_title'     => 'About',
    'post_name'      => 'about',
    'post_content'   => 'This is an about page. Feel free to edit or delete this page.',
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'post_author'    => $user_id, // or "1" (super-admin?)
    'post_type'      => 'page',
    'menu_order'     => 1,
    'comment_status' => 'closed',
    'ping_status'    => 'closed',
 ));  

// Find and delete the WP default 'Sample Page'
$defaultPage = get_page_by_title( 'Sample Page' );
wp_delete_post( $defaultPage->ID );

  restore_current_blog();
}
```

I'm adding this code in my child theme functions.php file. Any suggestion to fix this issue.

Comment: Hi. What do you mean by not working? It doesn't create page? Doesn't delete the sample page? Produces fatal error? etc.

Comment: @JackJohansson Yes, not creating the page and not deleting the sample page but does not show any error.

Comment: Hmm, it appears @Nikolay is right. It must be in your main site's `functions.php`, or a plugin.

Comment: @JackJohansson no luck, I'm trying the same with functions.php file and also with one plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you provided works great on my multisite. I am putting it in a network activated plugin though. Try the same.

Comment: I'm trying the same, as built one plugin and that plugin is network activated. But no luck. Will you please explain your setup.

Comment: @webtuts4u It uses subdomains for subsites, WP 4.8, PHP 5.6.29, I am creating the sites from /wp-admin/network/site-new.php and putting me as the admin of the new site.

Answer (score 2):

The "wpmu_new_blog" hook has been deprecated! Instead you should use the "wp_initialize_site" hook. For some reason Per Søderlind recomended using a priority higher than 100 in [this post](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_insert_site/).

The rest is pretty much the same. The only change that has been made (also taking advice from the post that Per Søderlind did) was to change the $blog_id to $new_site->blog_id. It didn't worked for me using only $blog_id.

Also, important detail. I've this piece of code as an mu-plugin.

```
add_action('wp_initialize_site', 'wpb_create_my_pages', 910, 1);

function wpb_create_my_pages(WP_Site $new_site){
  switch_to_blog($new_site->blog_id);

// create new page
  $page_id = wp_insert_post(array(
    'post_title'     => 'About',
    'post_name'      => 'about',
    'post_content'   => 'Page content goes in here',
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'post_author'    => 1,
    'post_type'      => 'page',
    'menu_order'     => 1,
    'comment_status' => 'closed',
    'ping_status'    => 'closed',
 ));  

// Find and delete the WP default 'Sample Page'
$defaultPage = get_page_by_title( 'Sample Page' );
wp_delete_post( $defaultPage->ID );

  restore_current_blog();
}
```

Hope this works!